# SQL String Concatenations

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

**I'm trying to resolve a challenge in HackerRank. The output I expect is**

```
Ashely(P)
Christeen(P)
Jane(A)
Jenny(D)
Julia(A)
Ketty(P)
Maria(A)
Meera(S)
Priya(S)
```

**The SQL code I am trying is**

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name, '(', SUBSTR(Occupation, 1, 1), ')') FROM OCCUPATIONS;
```

**The erorr I'm getting is**

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
```

**The table format:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJl3Q.png)

Please help me in resolving this challenge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle's [`CONCAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) function takes only two arguments.  As a clean workaround, you may use the `||` ANSI concatenation operator instead:

```sql
SELECT Name || '(' || SUBSTR(Occupation, 1, 1) || ')'
FROM OCCUPATIONS;
```

You *could* also use `CONCAT` with many nested calls:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(Name, CONCAT('(', CONCAT(SUBSTR(Occupation, 1, 1), ')')))
FROM OCCUPATIONS;
```

But, I prefer the `||` version above.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim! It works perfectly.

Comment: Yes it did. I clicked on this right mark. Hope it is okay now. Thank you again!